# Как достать значение вычисляемого поля?

Tags: c#, sql-server

В БД есть несколько таблиц, в одной из таблиц есть вычисляемое поле Status типа int, для рассчёта использующее CASE, данные из этой таблицы и пару хранимых процедур, которые в свою очередь используют данные из двух других таблиц. В программе хочу раскрасить строки DataGridView в зависимости от статуса. Но не выходит получить значение этого поля... в DataSet в колонке Status нет ни одного значения... Вычисляемые поля БД вообще можно засунуть в датасет?

Comment: Ну что, видимо, нельзя, да?
В общем, я решил создать "вычисляемое поле" в датасете, т.е. статус вычисляется на компьютере пользователя, а не на сервере БД. По-другому не смог.

Comment: А если вы делаете вручную `select *` в интерфейсе базы данных, поле `Status` корректно отображается? Подозоеваю, что проблема может быть на стороне базы данных.

Comment: Смотрю базу через SQL Server Management Studio, через редактор SQL-запросов в Visual Studio, через HeidiSQL - везде столбец заполнен вычисленными значениями типа int. В датасете столбец заполнен нулевыми значенимяи.

Answer (score 1):

Значения из вычисляемых полей в базе достаются точно так же, как и все остальные. Скорее всего в таблице в ваше поле ничего не попадает. Попробуйте заменить название поля на заведомо неправильное и проверить, будет ли генерироваться ошибка.

Можете создать рядом физическое поле с данными, попробовать привязаться к нему, а затем заменить его на калькулируемое.